# Using TEmbeddedWB in C++ Builder

Tags: delphi, c++builder, c++builder-10.3-rio, tembeddedwb

I am having little difficulty compiling a test app using `TEmbeddedWB` for RAD Studio Rio 10.3.3 from https://github.com/7even11/Delphi-EmbeddedWB

I just drop the a EmbeddedWB component on the form and compile. It compiles fine in Delphi. In C++ Builder there is an error:

**[bcc32c Error] EWB.IEConst.hpp(101): expected unqualified-id**

In **EWB.IEConst.hpp** file this happens in following lines:

```
static const System::Int8 BINDSTATUS_SERVER_MIMETYPEAVAILABLE = System::Int8(0x36);
static const System::Int8 BINDSTATUS_SNIFFED_CLASSIDAVAILABLE = System::Int8(0x37);
static const System::Int8 BINDSTATUS_64BIT_PROGRESS = System::Int8(0x38);
#define VER_NUM L" 14.70.0"
extern DELPHI_PACKAGE System::UnicodeString _MaskedChars;
static const int ADDRESS_NOT_VALID = int(0x7ffbfe1c);
#define ASS_MESS L"Please assign a WebBrowser before using this feature."
static const System::Int8 CACHEGROUP_ATTRIBUTE_BASIC = System::Int8(0x1);
```

The error is at the last line (`CACHEGROUP_ATTRIBUTE_BASIC`). I don't see anything why the above would trigger an error as there is a bunch of `static const System::Int8` above as well and they compile.

Any ideas what's the problem here?

Comment: Check if `CACHEGROUP_ATTRIBUTE_BASIC` has already been declared earlier using a `#define` macro. If so, the content of that macro will replace `CACHEGROUP_ATTRIBUTE_BASIC` in `EWB.IEConst.hpp`, creating an invalid declaration.

Comment: @RemyLebeau thanks, that was indeed the issue, conflict with `WinInet.h` and other headers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted by @RemyLebeau there was a conflict with previously defined constants in `WinInet.h` and other headers. I've updated the changes on https://github.com/7even11/Delphi-EmbeddedWB to make it easier for C++ Builder programmers to compile and use the component.